# How to insert keyframes in Graph's noise modifier to stop animation

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I'm following along this tutorial here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nl9mHgaP2X0

How evert the instructor doesn't specify, about the influence of the animation, how to to stop it. There's only one frame he has added. I have tried with the influence option, keyframe at 0=1.000 and at keyframe 100:1.000 but its not working.

So what I'm after is, a keyframe 0, the animation starts to vibrate/wobble motion, and at the 100th frame the animation comes slowly to a stop.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by enabling the *Restrict Frame Range* option, choose the end frame and the *Blend Out* value:

[image]

Comment: That looked like a hidden feature, but all good now. Thank you!